# Как отдать на скачивание файл по ссылке?

Tags: php, файлы, сервер, http

```
<?php
function file_force_download($file) {
if (file_exists($file)) {
// сбрасываем буфер вывода PHP, чтобы избежать переполнения памяти выделенной под скрипт
// если этого не сделать файл будет читаться в память полностью!
if (ob_get_level()) {
  ob_end_clean();
}
// заставляем браузер показать окно сохранения файла
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
// читаем файл и отправляем его пользователю
readfile($file);
exit;
}
}

file_force_download('1.mp4');
```

Данный код загружает файлы с сервера, как переделать что бы загружал файлы по ссылке с другого сайта например http://site.ru/1.mp4 или мою аватарку с этого сайта:

```
file_force_download('https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLp0X.png?s=64&g=1');
```

Думал что и так должно работать, но нет- в чем проблема?

Comment: Вместо `file_exists` - `$handle=@fopen($file,'r'); if ($handle) { //дальше ваш код`. Только учтите, что нужно отдавать правильные заголовки для каждого типа файла

Comment: @DaemonHK  Благодарю- работает, только нужно в конце убрать header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));   иначе файлы уродует(не открываются после загрузки). Не могли бы объяснить почему? Нужно было в ответ писать, а не в комент. Еще для тех, кто будет искать ответ на подобный вопрос- нужно в ссылке писать http.

Comment: Точно сказать не могу, не эксперт, но при попытке скачать картинку со стороннего сайта (которая скачалась багованным файлом), при просмотре в редакторе увидел сначала код из браузера, а уже потом начало картинки (а может и всю, не знаю). Подозреваю функции `ob_`, которые отдают, по сути, текущий контент, то есть мы сначала пытаемся отрисовать контент на странице, а потом скачиваем его. Теоретик из меня, правда, такой себе)